# GRASS7.8 setup to work externally in Python

Tags: python, grass-gis

I am following the instructions in https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Python:_GRASS_GIS_7_with_existing_location to setup GRASS 7.8 to work with Python 3.6 for Windows. GRASS 7.8 was installed with a QGIS 3.10 installation.

The script throws an error on the last line of my code and I am not able to get any further - TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' .

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

grass7bin_win = '\QGIS 3.10\bin\grass78.bat'
gisdb = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "grassdata")
location = "/newLocation"
mapset = "mapset_first"


if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    grass7bin = grass7bin_win
else:
    raise OSError('Platform not configured.')

startcmd = [grass7bin, '--config', 'path']

p = subprocess.Popen(startcmd, shell=False,
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
    print(sys.stderr, "ERROR: Cannot find GRASS GIS 7 start script (%s)" % startcmd)
    sys.exit(-1)
gisbase = out.strip('\n\r')
```

I have tried using `gisbase = out.strip(b'\n\r')`, and this prevents the error from occurring on this line but it causes an error on the next line  - TypeError: str expected, not bytes - for `os.environ['GISBASE'] = gisbase`

Answer (score 0):

gisbase is the top level directory for the GRASS installation, so by setting it to this you can avoid this error. gisbase = r'C:/GRASS GIS 7.8'